# Simple_captcha image not getting displayed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, captcha

> Captcha image is not displayed on the
>   ui, instead it just shows
>   simple_captcha.jpg. When i try to
>   access the image through url i get
>   following error:-

"Postscript delegate failed `/tmp/magick-XXKDifRg':  @ error/ps.c/ReadPSImage/779:`(null)'"

Thanks,
Anubhaw

Comment: how you generate captcha

Comment: I am using simple_captcha plugin to generate captcha

Answer (score 0):

With Rails 3 simple_captcha gem will work if you change the application's route.rb file, for example:

```
YourApp::Application.routes.draw do
#...
  match 'simple_captcha/:id', :to => 'simple_captcha#show', :as => :simple_captcha
#...
end
```

Otherwise it produces no image cause it doesn't even arrive to the gem's controller.